# Error on BSCSCAN : Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI

Tags: cryptography, solidity, smartcontracts, remix, bscscan

I'm really new to coding and crypto creation but i'm trying to verify my contract source since 2 hours but i always get the error :

" Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI
Found the following ContractName(s) in source code : Token
But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)"

Here is my code :

```
 //SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;


contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    uint public totalSupply = 100000000000000000 * 10 ** 18;
    string public name = "No Marketing Coin";
    string public symbol = "NOMK";
    uint public decimals = 18;
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    
    constructor() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address owner) public returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
       emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[from] -= value;
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;   
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns (bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;   
    } 
}
```

Thanks to everyone if you help me !

Comment: is this the only contract file u have?

Comment: This error usually comes from mismatching compiler config (amount of optimization iterations, exact solidity version, ...) or using imports in a non-current version. Since your code doesn't use any imports, i'm guessing the first option... Can you share link to the live contract, and compiler config that you've used before the deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message when I was verifying my smart contract on the rinkeby testnet, I happened to use Remix for deployment.

The Solution:

When I switched to Hardhat, copied my contract codes from my code editor. Then Boom! It worked, my contract was verified.

Don't know why pasting from remix directly wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but I suggest you to make sure that the compiler version is exactly the same as in Remix and that the license field is set to the same as in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by setting optimization to 200.

[image]